# BCrypt hash error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bcrypt

this is my code for hashing password and for compare existing password into existing module with a password that has been sended on body request:

```
        //hash password of document that use this schema
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, null, null, function (err, hashed) {

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            user.password = hashed;

            //next api
            next();
        }
    })
});

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (password) {

    //refer at userSchema
    var user = this;

    //return method of bcryot library that compare two string: original password and password hashed
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);

};
```

But compare this error message:

```
Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (Not a valid BCrypt hash.)
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolved !!! Into the database i have a lot of user's password not hashed and when i try to login, with `bcrypt.compareSync (password, user.password);` it expected that has been hashed password.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `null` twice. I'd wager that you've wrapped this function inside the `bcrypt.genSalt` function(if you haven't , do so). You need to pass it the bcrypt salt where the first `null` is written.

Here's a full example:

```
userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  const SALTROUNDS = 10;  // or another integer in that ballpark
  const user = this;
  if(!user.isModified('password')) {
    return next();
  }

  bcrypt.genSalt(SALTROUNDS, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, (error, hash) => {
      if (error) { return next(error); }

      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```